# Writing XML code using QXmlStreamWriter

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qstring

How can I Write a XML text inside a XML?

```
QXmlStreamWriter xmlWriter(&file);
(...)
QString xmlCode = "This is a <b>XML</b> code. And should be written as is it";
xmlWriter.writeStartElement("start");
xmlWriter.writeCharacters(xmlCode);
xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
```

The output should be:

```
<start>
    This is a <b>XML</b> code. And should be written as is it
</start>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can by using the [write method on the QXmlStreamWriter's](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamwriter.html#device) device directly; example:

```
QXmlStreamWriter xmlWriter(&file);
xmlWriter.writeStartElement("start");
xmlWriter.writeCharacters("");  // This will open and close <start> tag correctly
xmlWriter.device()->write(xmlCode.toLatin1().constData(), xmlCode.length());
xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
```

It was also suggested here: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/60045-writing-raw-data-into-xml-sub-node

Comment: If some part of xmlCode need to be escaped Qt::escape() could be used from <QTextDocument>.

Comment: Change `xmlWriter.device()->write(xmlCode.toLatin1().constData(), xmlCode.length());` to `xmlWriter.device()->write(xmlCode.toUtf8().constData(), xmlCode.toUtf8().length());` to prevent conversion of non-ASCII characters to "?" signs.